# Assign memory address to pointer

Tags: c++, pointers, driver

I am trying to assign a memory address to a pointer but cannot get it to compile.
The address is a memory mapped hardware register.

```
#include <memory>

template<void* Address>
struct ClassAImpl {
    uint64_t* Register = reinterpret_cast<uint64_t*>(Address);
};

uint8_t arrA[10] = { 1, 2, 3, 4 };
using ClassA1 = ClassAImpl<(void*)&arrA>;       // error: the address of the 'void' subobject of 'arrA' is not a valid template argument
using ClassA2 = ClassAImpl<0x8767876787678767>; // error: could not convert template argument '9756915996444559207' from 'long unsigned int' to 'void*'


template<uint64_t Address>
struct ClassBImpl {
    uint64_t* Register = reinterpret_cast<uint64_t*>(Address);
};

uint8_t arrB[10] = { 1, 2, 3, 4 };
using ClassB1 = ClassBImpl<(void*)&arrB>;       // error: conversion from 'void*' to 'long unsigned int' in a converted constant expression       
using ClassB2 = ClassBImpl<0x8767876787678767>; // This compiles.
```

I want to make both ClassA1 from a pointer to a buffer, and ClassA2 from a fixed address.

I am compiling C++ using Gcc 8.2

Comment: Is there a reason the address is a template value?

Comment: `void*` is not a valid type to use for a template parameter. There is really no need to use templates at all in this situation.

Comment: I want to make ClassB1 and ClassB2 different types based on the location of the memory mapped register, and I want the hardware access to be encapsulated in the class. This works if I do 'using ClassB2 = ClassBImpl<0xdeadbeefUL>'. Then I want to do 'using ClassB1 = ClassBImpl<(void*)&arrb>' so I can do some module testing of ClassBImpl.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what you are trying to achive but you are falling in odd behavior of non type template parameters. Non type template parameter can't be instantiated with temporaries. From https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_parameters:

> "For pointers to objects, the template arguments have to designate the
>   address of a complete object with static storage duration and a
>   linkage (either internal or external), or a constant expression that
>   evaluates to the appropriate null pointer or std::nullptr_t value."

```
using ClassA1 = ClassAImpl<(void*)&arrA>; - temporary
using ClassA2 = ClassAImpl<0x8767876787678767>; - template argument is constant expression, template parameter is pointer to void, doesn't make any sense
using ClassB1 = ClassBImpl<(void*)&arrB>; - temporary
using ClassB2 = ClassBImpl<0x8767876787678767>; - constant expression which can be used as template parameter uint64_t
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you want something like:

```
#include <stdint.h>

uint64_t (&hw_regs)[10] = *reinterpret_cast<uint64_t(*)[10]>(0xdeadbeefUL);
uint64_t &hw_reg0 = hw_regs[0];
```

Make the referenced objects `volatile` if you need to.  If you’re asking about the right caliber of bullet for shooting yourself in the foot, you know what you’re doing.  Section [expr.reinterpret.cast] of the Standard allows this cast, but of course the reference is not safely-derived.